# What do you call it when someone agrees just to avoid an argument?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

(A) asks, 'Do you think this is a good idea?'
(B) says, 'Yes, l do', - but (B) is more on the side of 'no' not 'yes', but (B) tells (A) what they want to hear so (B) doesnt have to talk about 'the idea'. What is (B)s comment called?
Is it a lie as its an untruth? Or something different?
(B) says its not lying.
(A) says it is as its not the truth.

Comment: Lying. Telling an untruth. Telling someone what they want to hear.

Comment: Being a ***yes man***

Comment: It's called "unclear".

Comment: *Wimping out*? It would help a lot if you could add some more information to your question. Specifically, are you looking for a single word, a phrase, maybe a colorful idiom...? If you want a single word, were you thinking of a verb for the action, or a noun for the person? Or maybe an adjective? Do you want a term with positive, negative, or neutral connotations? Adding an example sentence showing how you would use the term, with a ___ where the term would go, would be very helpful (and is technically required for a single-word-request, if that's what you want). Good luck!

Comment: @1006a - Hopefully OP will weigh in.  If not, I would like to, as the person who started the attempt to rescue a messy but interesting question.  I would like to see an adjective to describe such a person, or a noun to describe the process or the tendency.  One of my children is exactly like this, and I need a succinct way to let teachers know about his tendency to just say whatever he thinks they want to hear.  It's a product of his perceptiveness, people skills and anxiety.

Comment: @aparente001 Why don't you ask your own, separate question? If the OP doesn't come back, we won't ever get a selected answer, and if the OP does come back there's no guarantee that their target answer is the same as yours. In particular, I'm guessing the OP might prefer a more pejorative term than what you probably need.

Comment: @1006a - Okay, good idea, but I think I'll just wait a day or two to be sure.

Comment: Married 30 years, and likely to stay that way.

Comment: @1006a - I'm currently going with "going with the flow."  If it still looks good to me in a few days I think I'll *go with the flow*!  I.e. leave it at that.

Comment: @aparente001 glad you got a response here that works for you. You could also look at negative phrases, like *s/he doesn't want to make waves*.

Comment: @1006a - Yes, I like that better, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a single word rather than an idiom, I think **placate** works well.

From Merriam Webster:

Placate

Transitive verb

:  to soothe or mollify especially by concessions :  appease

Answer (score 1):

They are probably ***playing along*** (with you) just to avoid an argument.

TFD(idioms):

> **[play along](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+along)** (with somebody/something)
>   to seem to support or be friendly to someone or something
>
> He knew that if he didn't play along with the reporters, they would
>   write unpleasant stories about him.
>   I don't really like their idea
>   that much but for now, it is probably a good idea simply to play
>   along.
>
> Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
>   University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.

Comment: and related: "Go along to get along."

Answer (score 1):

B is *humoring* A.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humor):

> <sup>2</sup> humor
> *verb*
> transitive verb
> 1
> : to soothe or content (someone) by indulgence : to comply with the temperment or inclinations of • The only way to get along with him is to *humor* him. • I know you don't agree, but just *humor* me.

Answer (score 1):

They're **[going with the flow](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+with+the+flow)** -

> To do what other people are doing or to agree with other people
> because it is the easiest thing to do
>
> *I wasn't very keen on the decision but it was easier just to go with*
> *the flow.*

Answer (score 0):

### [Acquiesce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce)

> to accept, comply, or submit tacitly or passively.

When you acquiesce (to someone), you give them what they want even though you would rather not. Which fits your description.

Answer (score -1):

In more than 1 word: conflict averse.

Comment: I don't think "aversive" is what is wanted.  According to the Collins English Dictionary for example it means "tending to dissuade or repel".  See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aversive

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the part that was incorrect. // I like this proposal!  Could you provide some documentation, so I can upvote your answer?